# Editing Fields on a Content Type

Tags: entities, nodes

I am trying to get edits in a content type's fields to be displayed and reflected in the view.

Here is a picture of the settings followed by how they are being displayed.

[image: settings]

[image: display]

There is no book type being displayed which should group the books into how they have been assigned.

Also the body is appearing above the rest of the fields even though I have it in a different order in the display settings.

I am saving the settings using the 'save' button at the bottom of the screen. I have cleared all the caches. I have logged in and out again but nothing is changing when I edit the manage fields or manage display screens.

What am I doing wrong here?

thank you.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the answer! I just checked the view responsible and Book Type was present. I removed it and added it again adding the specific HTML tag and css style I wanted but it still does not appear. Any other checks I can do? This is driving me mad!

Comment: The problem is fixed, I was editing the wrong view for one thing and filtering the content wrongly. It was a case of having 2 Views with a very similar name. Thanks a lot for your help.